# ui-autocomplete вывести большой объем данных быстро

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, autocomplete

Есть код для ui-autocomplete, определен в  `$(function() {}`:

```
 $("#accountValue").autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetAccountNumbers", "Diary")',
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { filter: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response(data);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
        });
 $(".ui-autocomplete").css({ "max-height": "300px", "max-width": "260px", "box-sizing": "border-box", "-ms-box-sizing": "content-box", "-moz-box-sizing": "border-box", "-webkit-box-sizing": "border-box", "overflow": "auto" });
```

Метод-обработчик:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetAccountNumbers(string filter)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var sessionHelper = new SessionHelper(this.HttpContext);
            result = sessionHelper.AccountNumbers.Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item) && item.ToLower().StartsWith(filter.ToLower())).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
        }
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Метод-обработчик возвращает большое кол-во записей (около 24 тыс.), что сильно тормозит работу скрипта. Как можно увеличить скорость? Может быть динамическая загрузка данных? Или с сервера отдавать частями? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

**Update!**
На сервере данные достаются быстро. Тормозит, потому что происходит много вызовов метода-обработчика. (спасибо **@teo van kot** за наводку). Вопрос как не дергать метод так часто.

Answer (score 1):

Ради чего вам в автокомплитере возвращать большое количество записей? Ведь очевидно, что на экран все равно не поместится больше 30.

На сервере просто ограничите количество возвращаемых записей из БД. Или, если вам все же необходимо разное количество записей в различных случая - передавайте этот параметр в метод:

```
url: '@Url.Action("GetAccountNumbers", "Diary", new { RowNumber = 30 })',
```

Comment: Если на экран не помещаются записи - появляется скрол. Большое количество записей - на случай, если пользователь не будет вводить какой-нибудь текст, а просто будет скролить. Получается просто выпадающий список со всеми возможными значениями.

Comment: @Daria у вас список перерисовывается при каждом нажатии клавиши. То есть на каждое нажатие - запрос на сервер идет. Если вы и так сразу список весь тянете - делайте все на клиенте, не обращаясь на сервер, у автокомплитера есть такая возможность

Comment: @ teo van kot "у вас список перерисовывается при каждом нажатии клавиши." - как вариант можно было бы на сервере брать только, например, 50 записей и возвращать клиенту. Но как указать с какой записи брать (чтобы не брать все время один и тот же участок)? А что можно сделать на клиенте для ускорения загрузки, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Daria чтобы понять как на клиенте ускорить, надо посмотреть, а лагает ли клиент вообще. Посмотрите что происходит при загрузке в браузере (В хроме и фаерфоксе есть специальные утилиты). И если нет - надо уже смотреть серверный код, которого у вас в вопросе нет